# Need to Remove description in New form

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I Need to remove the Description in the New form for the List how to do this ?

Comment: Why Designer? You can't delete the description from List Settings > [field] > description ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new list form, you should be able to find the `<TR>` that associates with the "Description" and you can add some CSS to hide it:

```
<tr style="display:none;">
...
...
</tr>
```